# template specialization for special value of integer parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, template-specialization

I am struggling with template specialization for integer parameters, maybe it is simply impossible?

What I tried out:

```
template< int COUNT, typename REMOVE, typename ...T>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl
{
    using Type= typename RemoveFirstElementsImpl<COUNT-1, T...>::Type;
};

template< typename ...T>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl<0, T...>
{
    using Type= TypeContainer<T...>;
};


template < int COUNT, typename ... T >
struct RemoveFirstElements
{
    using Type = typename RemoveFirstElementsImpl< COUNT, T...>::Type;
};
```

Results in

> error: partial specialization is not more specialized than the primary template because it replaces multiple parameters with a pack expansion

Then I thought about SFINAE with something like:

```
template < int COUNT, typename = typename std::enable_if<COUNT==0>::type, typename HEAD, typename ... T >
struct RemoveFirstElements
{
    using Type= TypeContainer<T...>;
};
template < int COUNT, typename = void, typename HEAD, typename ... T >
struct RemoveFirstElements
{
    using Type= RemoveFirstElements<COUNT-1, T...>
};
```

But I have no idea how to get the combination of parameter packs and default parameters to run.

Maybe I am on the complete wrong way. What I want to achieve is to get a parameter list where the first n parameters are removed from my TypeContainer which is simply an extended std::tuple. I only need the type itself not any parameters and I need only on the types and not on any object.

Comment: Do not drop `typename REMOVE`

Comment: @DieterLücking I am still struggling! What do you mean with your comment. I can't get my code to work with adding a REMOVE again.

Comment: Look at the answer of @Jarod42

Comment: OK, catch the point... ! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
template<int COUNT, typename ...Ts> struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl;

template<>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl<0>
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl<0, T, Ts...>
{
    using type = std::tuple<T, Ts...>;
};

template<int N, typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl<N, T, Ts...>
{
    using type = typename RemoveFirstElementsImpl<N - 1, Ts...>::type;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c799d633f0dfd73)

Comment: Yepp! I got it now to run. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all:

> partial specialization is not more specialized than the primary template because it replaces multiple parameters with a pack expansion

The partial specializations must be more specialized than the primary. In your case, we have one element that is more specialized (`0` vs `COUNT`) and one that is less specialized `Ts...` vs `T, Ts...` The specialization be at least as specialized in every argument pair.

So we *could* add two specializations for your base case:

```
template <int, typename...> struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl;

// base case 1
template <>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl<0>
{
    using type = TypeContainer<>; // prefer lower-case type
};

// base case 2
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl<0, T, Ts...>
{
    using type = TypeContainer<T, Ts...>;
};

// recursive case
template <int COUNT, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl<COUNT, T, Ts...>
: RemoveFirstElementsImpl<COUNT-1, Ts...>
{ };
```

---

That works, but it's unsatisfying. Let's pick a different approach altogether. We could actually pop off elements as we go:

```
template <int COUNT, typename TC>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl
: RemoveFirstElementsImpl<COUNT-1, tail_t<TC>>
{ };

template <typename TC>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl<0, TC>
{
    using type = TC;
};
```

Or we could do it as one iteration with `index_sequence`:

```
template <int COUNT, typename... Ts>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl
: RemoveFirstElementsImpl2<COUNT, TypeContainer<Ts...>,
                           std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) - COUNT>
{ };
```

with:

```
template <int COUNT, typename TC, typename Seq>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl2;

template <int COUNT, typename TC, size_t... Is>
struct RemoveFirstElementsImpl2<COUNT, TC, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = TypeContainer<get_nth_t<Is+COUNT, TC>...>;
};
```

Where `get_nth_t<N, TC>` is a metafunction to be implemented that returns the the `N`th type in the given `TypeContainer`. A sample implementation might be:

```
template <int N, typename TC>
struct get_nth;

template <int N, typename TC>
using get_nth_t = typename get_nth<N, TC>::type;

template <int N, typename... Ts>
struct get_nth<N, TypeContainer<Ts...>> {
    using type = std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
};
```

Comment: `tuple_element_t` is quite inefficient.

Comment: @T.C. It's just an example implementation of one of the three solutions presented.

Comment: Thanks! I still can't see how your first addition fits to my code. I can't get it compiled. Can you add the rest to your first example? I still have only endless error lists...

Comment: @Klaus Added the full template for `RemoveFirstElementsImpl`

Comment: @Klaus Why not? What's the error? This is also the same as [Jarod42's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32570349/2069064)

Comment: I will check for my compilation problems next days. Today I run hard out of time. Our security stuff is waiting to switch off the lights now :-) But thank you very much for the many solutions you provide. I will take a look later!